# Is this a correct way to justify this step?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{B} (V)$ be the vector space of bilinear forms and
$\beta=\{ v^{1}, \ldots, v^{n}\}$ an ordered basis of $V$.

Define  $\psi_{\beta}: \mathcal{B} (V) \to \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$ such that:

$$
( \psi_{\beta}(H) )_{ij}=H(v^{i},v^{j}) \quad \text{ for all } 1 \leq i,j \leq n
$$ prove that $\psi_{\beta}$ is linear.

**Proof:**

*Here is the part of the proof where i think is all the information needed for the question*

1. Let $H_{1} \in \mathcal{B} (V)$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}$.

   By definition,
   we have that for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$ :
   $$
   \Biggl( \psi_{\beta}(aH_{1}) \Biggr )_{ij} = (aH_{1})(v^{i},v^{j})
   $$
   By definition of scalar product $aH_{1}$:
   $$
   \Biggl( \psi_{\beta}(aH_{1}) \Biggr )_{ij} = a(H_{1}(v^{i},v^{j}))
   $$
   Again by definiton:
   $$
   \Biggl( \psi_{\beta}(aH_{1}) \Biggr )_{ij} = a\Biggl(\psi_{\beta}(H_{1}) \Biggr)_{ij}
   $$

   *Here is the step where I have a doubt*

   > Since $a$ does not depend on either $i$ or $j$:
   > $$
   > \Biggl( \psi_{\beta}(aH_{1}) \Biggr )_{ij} = \Biggl(a\psi_{\beta}(H_{1})\Biggr)_{ij}
   > $$

   > **First comment:** I have seen this argument a lot of times but **I am not sure if this is applicable here**

   > **Second comment and question:**
   > I prefer to think that the function $( . )_{ij}: 
   >   \mathbb{F}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{F}$ (i.e. function that takes a matrix and return
   > its "ij" entry) is linear. Is this a correct way to justify this step? Or is the
   > previous step enough?

   Therefore:

   $$
   \psi_{\beta}(aH_{1}) = a\psi_{\beta}(H_{1})
   $$

Thanks in advance, appreciate any feedback.

Comment: This is correct. The last step "$a$ does not depend on either $i$ or $j$" is simply the scalar multiplication of $\mathbb F^{n\times n}$.

Comment: It seems that this is your first time using internet so let me tell you that writing in ALLCAPS in internet is the equivalent of yelling. Please, don't yell at us.

Comment: I will edit that sorry

Comment: Much obliged @Taladris